# Where can I find the forms to file an extension for my patent review?

Tags: extension

I need to file an extension on my patent, for the patent review process. The examiner told me there is a nominal $100.00 fee to accomplish this.  Please direct me to the appropriate form and mechanics for accomplishing this.

Comment: Can’t you just ask the examiner?

Comment: @EricShain ideally the examiner should have provided that, but I could see, re: the lapse, not wanting to bug the examiner. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are looking for a one month extension of time for responding to an office action. The fee for this for a small entity is $100.

The form can be found at [the USPTO](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/sb0022.pdf).

Fill this out then file it at the USPTO.

Comment: It isn't necessary to pay the time extension fee until the actual substantive response is filed.